# How to place my custom HTML form on google search results page

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

Recently I came across a lead generator tool which lets me search LinkedIn contacts via the google search and the resulting links are being shown beside the google search results in the empty white space . [image: Screenshot]

It catches all the links on the current page and shows them on the right side. I would like to do something similar. How can I achieve this ? Is there any help available from google APIs ? How can I get my custom form on the Google Search results page ?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it the other way round. Spider the page the user asked for in the google search. Then ask LinkedIn for your intel via the REST-API (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) and then manipulate the DOM. Or would that not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: will try that n get back 2 u